# Can I prevent PlantUML showing the Java Duke Icon when running on MacOS

Tags: java, plantuml

When I use a PlantUML `SourceStringReader` from my Java code on MacOS, the Duke icon bounces around in my Dock. This doesn't happen for the process until it loads its first PlantUML class.

The code is

```
import net.sourceforge.plantuml.FileFormat
import net.sourceforge.plantuml.FileFormatOption
import net.sourceforge.plantuml.SourceStringReader
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File

fun List<String>.toSvg(): String {
    val reader = SourceStringReader(this.joinToString("\n"))
    return ByteArrayOutputStream().use {
        val fileFormatOption = FileFormatOption(FileFormat.SVG)
        reader.generateImage(it, fileFormatOption)
        String(it.toByteArray(), Charsets.UTF_8)
    }
}
```

Evaluating `FileFormatOption(FileFormat.SVG)` causes the icon to appear.

My guess is that PlantUML is initialising some graphics subsystem that is causing the Mac to show the icon in the dock - can I not show the icon?

Comment: You need to provide more information in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Also can you post the output of jps when its rendering the SVG?

Comment: Blimey people are quick to close questions round here these days! I think that it's starting a new JVM because the Duke icon pops up as soon as I load any PlantUML code, and that doesn't happen usually. Maybe that's a side-effect of it starting a graphics subsystem or something. Will investigate

Comment: Hmm, Duke thinks he's running JUnitStarter, so I guess there is no new JVM.

Comment: As far as I remember, Java processes do not have a tray icon on Mac, until they initialize an UI framework. As https://plantuml.com/gui exists, the library may initialize something even if it won't use it. Looking at their issue tracker, this may be the case: https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/121 - I simply searched for ***Mac***.

Comment: @tevemadar thanks for the steer, if you could vote to reopen I can post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that `FileFormatOption` loads the `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` class, which initialises AWT, which pops up the dock icon.

Running `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true")` before the first call to PlantUML solves the problem.

Running PlantUML directly, there is a `-headless` option: `java -jar plantuml.jar -headless -verbose some-file`